# Google Cloud Platform kubernetes GuestBook example not running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm trying to follow the directions to get the Google Cloud Platform kubernetes GuestBook example running. I've got a "kubernetes-guestbook-example" project ID with billing enabled in the Google Developer's Console under my account and i do a "gcloud auth login" to ensure i'm running as that account. Step zero says that i should make sure i have "turned up a Kubernetes cluster". I think i've done this. I also run "gcloud config set project kubernetes-guestbook-example". Then i run "hack/dev-build-and-up.sh" from the kubernetes subdirectory and it produces:

```
Building local go components
Building release tree
Packaging release
Building launch script
Uploading to Google Storage
Release pushed (devel/jamesfremen/r20141001-192247).
Starting cluster using provider: gce
Release: gs://kubernetes-releases-68782/devel/jamesfremen/r20141001-192247
Project: kubernetes-guestbook-example (autodetected from gcloud config)
Error: The resource 'projects/kubernetes-guestbook-example' was not found
```

It seems to be a minor path issue. I think it's looking for examples/guestbook but i'm not sure how to configure it properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ok.. this doesn't work. I suspect it's a simple question, but perhaps a bit bleeding edge. Does anyone know if i would have better luck with Google Cloud Platform support?

Comment: It does look like a billing issue. Did you enable billing? I see five firewall rules but no instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but i recall that the problem occurred because billing must be enabled for the application in the Google Developer Console. An easy catch once you get used to the platform but non-obvious when you're climbing the learning curve.